# How can I find this letter from Ambrose?

Tags: church-fathers, reference-request, ambrose

In more than one work I encountered the following format:

(epist. 50[25],2f)

or

(epist. 49[59],3)

In referring to letters(?) written by Ambrosios of Milan, "epist." is explained as "Epistulae." which seems obvious.

But what does this indexing scheme refer to?

I would like to read the letter in the first example in either English, German or Latin.

Comment: The work you've found it in will probably include a full Bibliography entry for the collected works of Ambrose or something like that - knowing what edition that was from might help decode the references.

Comment: Can you post the work in which the citation was found?

Comment: Unfortunately not a single work in my hands using this numbering scheme, explains it. I found it in use in several books and academic papers.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of additional search I found part of the answer in a footnote of Thomas O Loughlin's "Celtic Theology", p. 50. It seems to be the case that the number in square brackets usually refers to the ordering according to the "seventeenth-century Maurist edition". Other numbers mentioned are typified as pertaining to the "ET" or / and "FC series."